# HTML5 アクセスキーについて

Tags: html5

HTMLではアクセスキーと呼ばれるものがあるそうなのですが、
アクセスキーにファンクションキーは使えないのでしょうか？

```
<button type="button" id="検索" name="検索"  accesskey="U" />
<button type="button" id="検索" name="検索"  accesskey="<F3>" />
```

上だと動くのですが、下だと動きません。
ただし、下との時はもともとF3の機能(検索)すら動かなくなります。

アクセスキーにファンクションキーを割り当てれないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

[7.5 Assigning keyboard shortcuts](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/editing.html#assigning-keyboard-shortcuts)
[同日本語訳](http://www.html5.jp/tag/attributes/accesskey.html#assigned-access-key)
によると、

> その値は、大文字・小文字を区別して順序付きスペース区切り固有トークンセットでなければいけません。 それぞれの値は、Unicodeのコード・ポイント長ひとつ分でなければいけません。

ということなので、特定のUnicodeの文字に該当しないファンクションキーは割り当てできないと思います。